# Git filter-branch --index-filter re-apply "clean" filter

Tags: performance, git

Git's `clean` and `smudge` filters can be used to store a different representation in the repository than is in the working tree. To apply a clean filter retroactively, I can run

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter /the/script.sh -- --all
```

where the script touches those files that need to be re-`clean`ed. Unfortunately, this is rather slow because it is updating the entire working tree for each commit. Is there a way to re-apply the clean filter within an `--index-filter`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: in your index filter, do `git checkout -- path/to/file`, have your way with it, and `git add` it again

Answer (score 0):

To re-clean efficiently without touching the file system, I filtered the output of `git ls-files -s` to match those files I was want to re-clean, then

```
git cat-file blob BLOB_TO_RECLEAN | my-clean-filter | git hash-object -w
```

to create a new object for the cleaned representation. I feed all of these new objects (reformatted to match the output of `git ls-files -s`) to `git update-index --index-info`. My filter makes the additional optimization of caching the translation from old blobs to new (cleaned) blobs so that any given blob is only cleaned once. See [`git fat index-filter`](https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat) for the complete implementation.